# django installation: cannot use pip to install django on linux(ubuntu)

Tags: python, django, pip

I tried to install django on ubuntu using pip. but unfortunately I got error like this. can someone explain this and tell me some ways to fix this?

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/franklingu/build/django   /setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-W5MhGe-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/franklingu/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use sudo use a virtual environment instead, like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
$ mkvirtualenv django_env
$ source django_env/bin/activate
(django_env) $ pip install django
(django_env) $ cd $HOME
(django_env) $ mkdir projects
(django_env) $ cd projects
(django_env)/projects $ django-admin.py startproject foo
(django_env)/projects $ cd foo
(django_env)/projects/foo $ python manage.py runserver
```

When you are finished; type `deactivate` to exit the virtual environment:

```
(django_env)/projects/foo $ deactivate
/projects/foo $
```

Comment: Oftentimes, this can be more trouble than it's worth. But I agree that virtual env is a useful tool.

Comment: why is that? as far as I know, virtual env should be safer?

Comment: @RobertMcGibbon its never more trouble; and the benefits far outweigh what I have mentioned here.

Comment: Never say never, @BurhanKhalid. Especially with the scientific stack, where you need lots of compiled native libraries (numpy/scipy/etc), there are a lot of disadvantages of virtualenv and pip. See for instance this twitter thread and Peter Wang's (cofounder of Continuum Analytics) comments. https://twitter.com/pwang/status/393440886152896512

Answer (score 9):

Try `sudo pip install django` instead.

Comment: thanks... since this error is "permission denied" then we should use sudo as the superuser?

Comment: Yes. Another option is to create a "virtual environment" in which you can install packages which won't be located in the system directories. This is useful if, for instance, you work on multiple projects that require different versions of django. http://docs.python.org/dev/library/venv.html

Comment: Strange, but it does not work for me with virutalenv, I have virtualenv activated, but simple pip install is attempting to access the global system directory. This never happened before in 4 years.

Answer (score 3):

The location which you are trying to install django "usr/local/lib/..."  is root owanership location.So for every command you would require
sudo.

Instead  of that you  can follow these stpes

1.Install vitrual environment

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
```

2.Create virtual env

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 testEnv
```

(Dont use sudo here it will make the environment root ownership.Here i am creating python 3 environment)

3.Activate that env using following command

```
$ source testEnv/bin/activate
```

4. Install django using the command

```
$ pip install django
```

5.Using the follwing command you can check the installed packages in that environment

```
$ pip freeze
```

**note:It is better to use pip commands without sudo.If we are using sudo that package will change to root ownership**