# Error when installing Django with pip

Tags: django, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to install Django 1.8.0 on my Ubuntu like this:

```
pip install Django==1.8.9
```

And this is the error Im getting:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.7.dist-info'
```

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: have you installed `django1.8.7` with sudo or using `easy_install`. Try to uninstall the old version first `pip uninstall django`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django installation: cannot use pip to install django on linux(ubuntu)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629685/django-installation-cannot-use-pip-to-install-django-on-linuxubuntu)

Comment: Agree with @Railslide.  You should be installing in a virtualenv.  Make sure to do source bin/activate on your virtualenv before running pip / django commands.  Installing django as sudo will create problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Run in shell:

```
sudo pip install Django==1.8.9
```

But, as said in comments, you better use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with or without [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). If you have **python 3.3+** the recommended approach is to use [`pyvenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) (with or without `virtualenvwrapper`) instead of `virtualenv`.