# exception error rising in installing virtualenv

Tags: python, django, exception, pip

I'm trying to install python virtualenv.
So i ran the command

```
pip install virtualenv
```

and I met these errors.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py'
```

Comment: Try running 'sudo pip install virtualenv'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django installation: cannot use pip to install django on linux(ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629685/django-installation-cannot-use-pip-to-install-django-on-linuxubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are installing the `virtualenv` package in a system level directory of a Mac. Mac uses an older Python (2.7.10) that comes pre-installed. To install the `virtualenv` package in the system directory you identified, you need to use `sudo` because writing to a system directory requires elevated privileges.

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Another option is to install it to a user directory using the `--user` option.

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

Comment: God, now I know why I hated python so much. Every single time I install something, something goes wrong. I installed the latest python2 and finally I can just go ahead and say pip install with confidence. You saved like a bazillion of my hours thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try running it with sudo:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

or else explicitly calling the python command

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```