# Django Python on a Mac via pip and HomeBrew - Getting Started

Tags: python, django, pip, homebrew

I am trying to get started with `Python` Web Programming with `Django`, so I installed `pip` first (via `HomeBrew`) and now the latest version of `Django`, but the following happens, which I have no idea what is wrong or what I should do next. Could someone please help me understand what is going on + what I need to do + what commands I should issue to resolve this, etc...?

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

$ pip install Django==1.11.7
Collecting Django==1.11.7
  Downloading Django-1.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 7.0MB 184kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from Django==1.11.7)
Installing collected packages: Django
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django'
```

Comment: You would have to use `sudo` to install into `site-packages`. However, that's not the recommended approach. It would be much better to use a virtualenv, and to use Python 3 (Django 1.11.x is the very last version to support Python 2). The Django Girls Tutorial is a good guide. See the [python installation](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/python_installation/) and [Django installation](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/) sections. If you wish, you can use brew to install Python 3 instead of downloading the installer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django installation: cannot use pip to install django on linux(ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629685/django-installation-cannot-use-pip-to-install-django-on-linuxubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because your user account doesn't have some permissions regarding the `Library` folder.

Use

```
sudo pip install Django==1.11.7
```

### Alternative way

You might also use

```
pip install --user Django
```

which installs Django following the user installation scheme. [This](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#inst-alt-install-user) page says:

> This scheme is designed to be the most convenient solution for users that **don’t have write permission to the global site-packages directory** or don’t want to install into it... Files will be installed into subdirectories of [site.USER_BASE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE).

---

**However**, I think that what you are doing isn't considered best practices.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.  I added `sudo` and finally got the message: `Successfully installed Django-1.11.7` One question though: What happens if I do `pip install --user Django` now (just like that, without mentioning version) after what I have already done with the sudo command?

Comment: I **guess** that it will install Django another time but this time in `~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` according to the links in the answer, and assuming that you have a framework build of Python.