# Pythonanywhere install modules permission denied error

Tags: pip, installation, pythonanywhere

How do you install `upstox`?  `pip install upstox` is not installing the module on a bash console.

```
11:54 ~ $ pip install upstox
Collecting upstox
  Using cached upstox-1.5.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from upstox)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): future in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from upstox)
Collecting websocket-client (from upstox)
  Using cached websocket_client-0.46.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): argparse in /usr/lib/python2.7 (from future->upstox)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): importlib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from future->upstox)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from websocket-client->upstox)
Installing collected packages: websocket-client, upstox
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket_client-0.46.0.dist-info'
11:54 ~ $
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That's a familiar combination, permission denied during pip install. You might look for answers to similar questions for different packages. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19629685/673991) suggests sudo or virtual environments, for example.

Answer (score 2):

[This help page on the PythonAnywhere site](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/) has instructions on a couple of extra things you need to do when using pip to install stuff there.  Essentially, you either need to use the `--user` flag or use a virtualenv.

Comment: pip install --user upstox successfully installed

Comment: from upstox_api.api import *
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import os, sys
from tempfile import gettempdir
import math
from time import sleep
import time
import schedule
import urlparse
from selenium import webdriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/veepsirtt/upstok/vp-demo-pythonantwhare.py", line 1, in <module>
    from upstox_api.api import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'upstox_api'

Comment: You need to make sure you're running using the same Python version as you installed for -- eg. if you're running your code with Python 3.6, you should have used pip3.6 to install.

Answer (score 0):

just use --user flag example:

```
pip3 install --user django-js-reverse
```