# Installing google cloud module on Ubuntu 16.04 returns error

Tags: python-3.x, permissions, pip, google-cloud-python

I tried to install google cloud module on Ubuntu 16.04 for python 3 but it shows `permission error 13`

this  error is shown many times during  installations for my python environment  `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2-0.9.1.egg-info`

Comment: can you show us the command you're using. you may need `sudo` prefix to install stuff.

Comment: pip install --upgrade gcloud

Comment: try `sudo pip install --upgrade gcloud `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip is not able to install packages correctly: Permission denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816674/pip-is-not-able-to-install-packages-correctly-permission-denied-error)

Comment: Yes , sudo worked

Comment: then accept the duplicate proposed to you

Comment: Done , ........

Comment: well, it's still opened. didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django installation: cannot use pip to install django on linux(ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629685/django-installation-cannot-use-pip-to-install-django-on-linuxubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

> For the sake of completeness I will answer this partly because:
>
> 1) the first duplicate suggested (although correct) is for Mac
>
> 2) the second duplicate suggestion is for Django and returns a different error.

---

As [Jean François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre) said in his comments use

```
sudo pip install --upgrade gcloud`
```

Without this command `pip` cannot access the root dictionary to write the appropriate files.  This is due to security reasons where *nothing can be written in the root dictionary* unless `sudo` prefix is specified so that only the superuser can allow security privileges.

See [Wikipedia for info on the `sudo` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike others suggest, it's not good practice to let `pip install` be called with `sudo` rights. Instead, you should use [chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown). You should give yourself rights to the directory or files and not use sudo.

You'll get the same effect, much more safely.